# Selecting two values in VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to get a value from a table in another sheet based on two values in the current sheet.

This is what I have in the first sheet
[image: sheet1]

And this is what I have in the second sheet
[image: sheet2]

At the moment I get the expected `indicador` from `sheet 2` for A1 cell (can be P01, P02, P03,...). But I want it to search based the cells A1 and B3, because B3 can assume equal values to different A1 values (P01, P02, P03,...).
Is it possible to select more than one value on `=VLOOKUP (value, table, col_index, [range_lookup])` ?

Comment: Try putting the data in the question rather than in images. (Use the "code" format to help preserve the layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

[image]

Formula in `F3`:

```
=INDEX(A2:A3,MATCH(1,INDEX((B2:B3=F1)*(C2:C3=F2),),0))
```

If you were looking to return the value `11` with the other two parameters, you can adapt this to a formula in F2:

```
=INDEX(A2:A3,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A3=F3)*(B2:B3=F1),),0))
```

You can obviously adapt this to your needs...

Comment: This does the work. Thanks.
But for future reference, is there any way where VLOOKUP can do something similar?

Comment: If you have control over your data, a helper column can come in handy then. But really, `INDEX` + `MATCH` is equally fast at least, and significantly faster than `VLOOKUP` at best. Try get into the habit of using this maybe lesser known combination.